# Alamofire return jpg image to Xcode

Tags: swift, uiimageview, alamofire

I am using alamofire to retreive an image from a webservice. The .jpg image is returned in the body of the response.

Can anybody guide me on how to display the retreived image on a uiImageView?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you include your code up to this point? SO isn't a code writing service, so it's best to show your progress and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: If you have directly the content data of an jpg, you can do `UIImage(data: thatData)`. Also, since you use Alamofire, you can use `Alamofire+Image`. But then, it's hard to tell what you've tried and what's wrong with your attempts...

Comment: @patrickb100 if my answer helped you, please accept it as answer. i will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you have already imageUrl and no restriction 3rd party libraries as you have also used `Alamofire`, so I think [`Kingfisher`](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) can come into play like this function :

```
func setup(imageUrl: String?) {
    if let imageUrl = imageUrl,
       let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholderImage"))
    } else {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholderImage")
    }
}
```